# I have this error: "unknown cipher type"

Tags: networking, server

I'm creating an ubuntu server. I'm totally new.

- The first redflag is when the pc is turning on, before everything is loaded, it fails in "a start job is running for wait for network to be configured".
- At the beginning of the installation I set an Static ip for the server. Well, now when I do:

```
ssh -2c servidor@192.168.0.2
```

it responds:

```
Unknown cipher type 'servidor@192.168.0.2'
```

where this ip is the static ip I set at the beginning.

Thank you for all of you that would try help me

Tutorial link I'm following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TowpySeDtTU&t=123s

at 1:54

Comment: Which ssh client are you using? What are you expecting the `-2c` argument to do?

Comment: OpenSsh I think it's called. I don't know what to expect because I'm following a tutorial because I'm a noob but i'm trying to learn haha

In the tutorial, the command allows you to enter the server

Comment: OK please [edit] your question to include a link to the tutorial if possible

Comment: For sure! It's in spanish, the tutorual says that -2c is "the second version of ssh compressed", I proceed to put the link in the publication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial you are following instructs you to type `-2C` not `-2c`. From `man ssh`, the `C` and `c` options are quite different:

> ```
>  -C      Requests compression of all data (including stdin, stdout,
>          stderr, and data for forwarded X11, TCP and UNIX-domain connec‐
>          tions).  The compression algorithm is the same used by gzip(1).
>          Compression is desirable on modem lines and other slow connec‐
>          tions, but will only slow down things on fast networks.  The de‐
>          fault value can be set on a host-by-host basis in the configura‐
>          tion files; see the Compression option.
>
>  -c cipher_spec
>          Selects the cipher specification for encrypting the session.
>          cipher_spec is a comma-separated list of ciphers listed in order
>          of preference.  See the Ciphers keyword in ssh_config(5) for more
>          information.
> ```

In particular, since `-c` expects an `cipher_spec` *argument*, it is taking `servidor@192.168.0.2` to be a cipher_spec rather than a hostname.

AFAIK, option `-2` (although accepted) is ignored, since OpenSSH no longer supports the SSH 1 protocol. So you should use either

```
ssh -2C servidor@192.168.0.2
```

or just

```
ssh -C servidor@192.168.0.2
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Now I face the another problem, I wrote it correctly but I get the following:

```
ssh: connect to host 192.186.0.2 port 22: No route to host
```